# Twig extension method argument which is not specified in twig filter

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, twig, knppaginatorbundle

This code is from the symfony *Knp-paginator-bundle* and lives in a Twig Extension class (`PaginationExtension.php`). I'm wondering (just curiosity) where the second argument: `SlidingPagination $pagination` in the render() method comes from, since this argument is not supplied in twig. Anyone an idea?

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('knp_pagination_render', array($this, 'render'), array('is_safe' => array('html'), 'needs_environment' => true))
    );
}

/**
 * Renders the pagination template
 */
public function render(\Twig_Environment $env, SlidingPagination $pagination, $template = null, array $queryParams = array(), array $viewParams = array())
{
    return $env->render(
        $template ?: $pagination->getTemplate(),
        $this->processor->render($pagination, $queryParams, $viewParams)
    );
}
```

In Twig the extension is used like this:

```
{{ knp_pagination_render(projects) }}
```

Comment: The first variable is injected by `Twig` because you've set the `need_environment` option to true, more information [here](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/advanced.html#environment-aware-filters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `SlidingPagination $pagination` comes from `projects`

in twig call: `{{ knp_pagination_render(projects) }}`

`\Twig_Environment $env` is inserted to all extension functions by twig.

Comment: Your last comment is only true if you provide the `needs_environment` option to the function/filter